# Get has_many from ActiveRecord::Relaiton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to get the has_many records from an ActiveRecord::Relation?

i.e. `Book.where(fiction: true).pages` as opposed to `Book.where(fiction: true).collect { |book| book.pages }`

Ideally I'd like to be able to get all the records using one ActiveRecord query, so I don't have to build up the array in memory, and make the code a little cleaner, especially when the relationship has multiple levels (i.e. `Book.where(fiction: true).pages.words`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the below,

```
Book.where(fiction: true).collect { |book| book.pages }
```

can be written as :

```
Page.joins(:book).where("books.fiction = ?", true)
```

Similar way :

```
Word.joins(page: :book).where("books.fiction = ?", true)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I already have the initial collection as a relation, like in a view? i.e. I have `@books` and want to get all words of those books.

Comment: @Asherlc yes. use `#includes` method like `Book.includes(:pages).where(fiction: true)`.. this is a single query and it solves the `N + 1` problem.

Comment: @Asherlc read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained my question well. Let's say I have just a variable which contains an ActiveRecord::Relation, and do not have access to the original query parameters. So that I want to take an instance variable of `@books` and find all the associated pages/words, given just the prebuilt ActiveRecord::Relation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may create separate `has_many` relation between parent object (lets say that it's `Library`) and `pages` with option `through`.

```
class Page
  belongs_to :book
end

class Book
  belongs_to :library
  has_many :pages
end

class Library
  has_many :books
  has_many :pages, through: :books
  has_many :fiction_books, -> { where(fiction: true) }, class_name: 'Book', foreign_key: 'library_id'
  has_many :fiction_pages, through: :fiction_books, source: :pages
end

Library.first.fiction_pages
```

I would notice that parent object will help you to build right architecture with too complicated logic, so instead of `Book.where(fiction: true).pages` you will write just `current_library.fiction_pages`

If the logic of application doesn't require such parent object, you may fake it via separate helper which can be placed in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_library

  protected

  def current_library
    @current_library ||= Library.first
  end

end
```

In this case all AR objects should be fetched via the library method or via the childs of library.